# How to change text in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm new to Android development, and have been able to set the text of `EditText` elements through XML code, but how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply call the `setText()` method. Here is an example:

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
e.setText("New Text");
```